# HTML text change on scroll position

Tags: jquery, html, css, text, scroll

I was wondering how you would go about using jquery to change the text of a paragraph through the scroll position. I have images that you scroll through and I want a fixed description of these images to change as the user passes by each one.

Comment: I don't understand that part: "change the text of a paragraph through the scroll position".
If you want a fixed text and a scrollable image, why don't you do 2 div, one scrollable with images and the other not scrollable with text?

Comment: I want each image to have a different description so I want a fixed description div that changes as the user scrolls past an image.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this :

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var div = $("MyDiv").scrollTop();

    //check the scroll of the page vs the scroll of the div containing the image.
    if($(this).scrollTop() > $("MyDiv").scrollTop() + 50)
    {
         $("SomeP").text("My new text");
    }

});
```